# Alternate approach for row_number

Tags: sql, partition, row-number

Suppose I have this:

```
Id  Code  Inactive
1   A     0
2   A     1
3   B     0
4   C     1
```

And I want this as result:

```
Id  Code  Inactive
2   A     1
3   B     0
4   C     1
```

**What is desired:** 
For each Code if there is an Inactive record, return it, otherwise return active one (Inactive = 0) 
**Why alternate approach for row_number:** 
I'd have a parameter which tells should just return active records or gives priority to inactive ones.

```
-- When InactiveHasPriority is false
select * from tbl where Inactive = 0
```

and now if ReturnInactiveIfExists = true, I'm looking for a simpler (less query change) and still efficient way to do a query instead of something like this:

```
-- When InactiveHasPriority is true
select * from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Inactive DESC) AS RowNo from tbl) t where t.RowNo = 1
```

looking for another approach to make second query as much as possible similar to the first one in order to not need to have much different queries for these two scenarios

Comment: @SadlyFullStack could be more clear from the two tables at the beginning. for each Code there could be 0, 1 (active or inactive) or 2 (active and inactive) records. So I'm just looking for another approach for second query to return inactive = 0 record for each Code ('A', 'B', 'C') if exists, otherwise return the existing record for that Code.

Comment: The requirement to make the two queries look the same is odd. What's the purpose?

Comment: @Schwern I just was trying to share a similar query for both scenarios (reuse it). But you are right. It seems odd for me myself after writing down the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement to make the two queries look as close as possible is quite odd, especially for such a simple query. It's unlikely you'll be able to come up with an alternative approach which is any closer.

What you can do is to turn the query into a CTE which is a bit easier to follow.

```
with tbl_active_first as (
  select
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Inactive DESC) AS RowNo
  from tbl
)
select *
from tbl_active_first
where RowNo = 1
```

And if you want to reuse it, make a [view](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_create_view.asp).

```
create view tbl_active as
  with tbl_active_first as (
    select
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Inactive DESC) AS RowNo
    from tbl
  )
  select *
  from tbl_active_first
  where RowNo = 1;
```

Then select from that.

```
select * from tbl_active
```

Comment: That's a great approach for me. I can create the CTE and based on the parameter I can include where condition dynamically as for first scenario (where Inactive = 0) and for second scenario (where RowNo = 1)

Comment: @Mehrdad Look into a SQL query builder. It makes your issue moot.